# PhpStorm user notification

Tags: deployment, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to always remind the user (in this case: myself), to get alerted every time on File upload if the FTP server is = (example FTP)?

##### Here is my situation and why I need this.

I have local files that I work on and upload them to a remote server after my codes are finished.

Usually, when I work on projects, I'm the only developer that works on that project for that website, but I've come across a project for a website where another developer is working on it at the same time.

I have backups locally, but the other developers work on a remote server, so every day if I forget to download the files before working on them and upload them to remote. The work of the other developer is gone and will be replaced with my old/new work.

I want to get a notification every time I work on that website before uploading.

**Does PhpStorm have that feature?** It's really hard not to mess up and ruin something, not my fault that he works on remote sever, but I don't want to mess up his hard work.

Comment: 1) You can use "Synchronize with deployed" so that you will have an overview of what files will be modified (and which way) before you do the upload. You can even merge the changes into a local file there. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-deployment-in-product.html#sync

Comment: 2) There is an option "Warn when uploading over newer file" that should warn if a file was modified/is newer than the local one (not sure how it will work if you both editing the same file at the same time: will it treat the more recent remote change as "it's OK" or not). Anyway, have a look and try -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-deployment-options.html . **P.S.** Sync is better here as it allows to preview the things before uploading.